# How to get/print data after downloading them on device using URLSession downloadTask?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swift5

I downloaded a JSON file from the internet and saved it on document directory. Then I moved the temp file location to my custom file location.
Now I want to print or access from my custom URL/file path where the data is saved.

Here's the code of downloading the file.

```
func downloadingContent() {

        let url = URL(string: "https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/file_example_JSON_1kb.json")

        URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url!) { (urlresponse, response, error) in

            guard let originalUrl = urlresponse else { return }

            do {
                let path = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)

                self.newUrl = path.appendingPathComponent("jsonFile")

                try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: originalUrl, to: self.newUrl!)
                print(self.newUrl!)
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

Here's the custom file path/URL I get after downloading the file.

```
file:///Users/fahimrahman/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4DA8E821-097A-4D66-BE95-CE51F3C52CD8/data/Containers/Data/Application/C7714D5E-6CBC-4E54-8619-C9C15EA739B3/Documents/jsonFile
```

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Load the data with `String(contentsOf: self.newUrl)`.
2. Rather than `downloadTask` use `dataTask` then you can save the data in `Documents` and use it directly.